# Need to apply casual leave application for 5 days at year end, how do I ask

Tags: management, employer-relations, leave-of-absence

How do I apply for leave for a week at the year-end when my team has three members and the manager isn't approving the leave due to dependency or some vague excuse. Also getting my leave approved at the manager's mercy is something I hate to do. I want to be direct but also feel I might violate Robert Greene's 19th Law "Don't offend the wrong person".

Comment: I had applied a 4 days consecutive leaves before and had to face her bad attitude towards approving it. So maybe that what I will be expecting again to happen as this time its the year end and my work is under support function

Comment: **Early.** Applying for that early would allow them to plan accordingly. As well as allowing for nagotiation / compromises (ok boss, I can't leave from 25-31 Dec... what about 1-7 January?).

Comment: Please give more context. Is this paid leave you are entitled to? Is this unpaid leave you want as a favor?

Answer (score 3):

> Please may I take X days leave on the following dates:

That should be all that's needed.

(The only reason to phrase it as a question, instead of just "I will be taking...", is politeness. It means the same thing).

If for some reason it's not all that's needed, there is a bigger problem than just the leave itself. For example you may wish to ask why you are being denied a benefit to which you are (presumably, depending on location and employment contract) legally and contractually entitled; or, you may simply wish to get a job where taking a few days off with several months' notice is acknowledged as reasonable, which it is. If your job leaves you in fear of offending someone just by asking for leave, something is wrong.

(Exceptions do sometimes apply - emergency services usually have to work over Christmas, for example, no matter how far in advance they try to book it - but if that applies to you, you'd have known it before you started that career).

Comment: Are you suggesting that you don’t have the right to any leave ever if there are too few staff?

Comment: Uh... no? What makes you think I was suggesting that?